# ssh works with port specified but not without

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

So if I try to ssh into our server without specifying the port I get asked for a password but if I specify -p443 it uses correctly from ssh-agent or whatever. Why does this happen? Is the key stored relating to the port used? Or is this somehow related to the way my devops team setup the infra security?

Answer (score 2):

You are using custom port. SSH client which is listening on the port 443 is configured to use public key, and the SSH client which is listening on 22 is expecting password.
It is also possible that port 443 is redirected to completely different machine.